# IE gets focus on iframe location change

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus, window.open

There is a third-party page with my iframe.
I want to open a new window from iframe then change iframe location to other and focus to new window.

```
user_clicks = function() {
    newwindow = window.open(new_window_url, "_blank");
    newwindow.focus();
    location.href = iframe_url;
}
```

It works in all browsers but not in IE. It returns focus back to page with iframe, when iframe location is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself
Placed blur on the second iframe url

```
setTimeout(function() {
    parent.blur();
}, 1000);
```

Worked with setTimeout only, because without - it only blinks at one moment and returned back to page with iframe.